# React select from Radix-UI conflicts with default value, how to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, react-select, radix

I have this component where I render 3 different selectors depending on the data I pass. The first selector once clicked, gets the data of the second one (without selection), the same for the second, and so on. What I am trying to achieve is that, if I select the first dropdown && the second one has only one item in the list I get that value will be pre-selected without letting the user select it by himself.

[image]

This is the parent component where I pass the default value to each selector:

```
const CreateBatchTemplateDialog: FC<Props> = ({ open, onClose }) => {
  const [localInstruments, setLocalInstruments] = useState<LocalInstrument[]>();
  const [corridors, setCorridors] = useState<Corridor[]>();
  const [corridorId, setCorridorId] = useState<string>();
  const [productSchemas, setProductSchemas] = useState<ProductSchema[]>();
  const [dowloaded, setDowloaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { data: localInstrumentsData } = useGetLocalInstrumentsQuery();
  const downloadFile = useDownloadFile();

  const [getProductSchemas] = useLazyGetProductSchemasQuery();

  const fetchingProductSchemaData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data: productSchema } = await getProductSchemas(corridorId);
      setProductSchemas(productSchema.data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (corridorId) {
      fetchingProductSchemaData();
    }
  }, [corridorId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localInstrumentsData?.data) {
      setLocalInstruments(localInstrumentsData.data);
    }
    setProductSchemas([]);
  }, [localInstrumentsData]);

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    setError,
    formState,
    setValue,
    reset: resetForm,
    getValues
  } = useForm<Inputs>({
    mode: 'onSubmit',
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const localInstrumentsOptions = useMemo(() => {
    setProductSchemas([]);
    return Array.isArray(localInstruments)
      ? localInstruments.map((i) => ({ label: i.name, value: i.name }))
      : [];
  }, [localInstruments]);

  const corridorsOptions = useMemo<SelectChoice[]>(() => {
    setProductSchemas([]);
    return Array.isArray(corridors)
      ? corridors.map((i) => ({
          label: i.label,
          value: i.id.toString()
        }))
      : [];
  }, [corridors, localInstruments]);

  const productSchemasOptions = useMemo(() => {
    return Array.isArray(productSchemas)
      ? productSchemas.map((i) => ({
          label: i.label,
          value: i.id.toString()
        }))
      : [];
  }, [productSchemas, corridors, localInstruments]);

  const onLocalInstrumentChange = (value: string) => {
    setDowloaded(false);
    setProductSchemas([]);
    setCorridorId(undefined);

    const corridorData = localInstruments?.find((i) => i.name === value);
    setCorridors(corridorData ? corridorData.products : []);

    setValue('localInstrument', value, {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldTouch: true,
      shouldValidate: true
    });
    setValue('corridor', '', {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldTouch: true,
      shouldValidate: true
    });
  };

  const onCorridorChange = (value: string) => {
    setDowloaded(false);
    setCorridorId(value);
    setProductSchemas([]);
    setValue('corridor', value, {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldTouch: true,
      shouldValidate: true
    });
    setValue('productSchema', '', {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldTouch: true,
      shouldValidate: true
    });
  };

  const onProductSchemaChange = (value: string) => {
    setDowloaded(false);
    setValue('productSchema', value, {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldTouch: true,
      shouldValidate: true
    });
  };

  const onSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (event: any) => {
    try {
      await handleSubmit(async (data) => {
        downloadFile(`payouts/schemas/${data.productSchema}/csv_template`);
        setDowloaded(true);
      })(event);
    } catch (error: any) {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          setFormErrors({
            error,
            setError,
            fields: Object.keys(schema.fields)
          }),
        50
      );
    }
  };

  const onDialogClose = (value: boolean) => {
    resetForm();
    onClose(value);
    setLocalInstruments([]);
    setCorridors([]);
    setCorridorId(undefined);
    setProductSchemas([]);
    setDowloaded(false);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={onDialogClose}>
      <DialogPortal>
        <DialogOverlay className="fixed inset-0 z-50 bg-inpay-green-700/90">
          <DialogContent
            onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
            className="fixed top-[50%] left-[50%] translate-y-[-50%] translate-x-[-50%] rounded-lg shadow-[0_0_6px_#B7BCBA]"
          >
            <DialogTitle className="flex h-12 items-center justify-between rounded-t-lg border-b border-b-inpay-pumice bg-white px-6">
              <DownloadIcon className="w-8 stroke-1 group-hover:stroke-1.5" />
              <span className="pr-12">Create batch template</span>
              <DialogClose
                aria-label="Close"
                className="outline-none focus:outline-none"
              >
                <XIcon className="-m-1 h-8 w-8 outline-none focus:outline-none" />
              </DialogClose>
            </DialogTitle>
            <div className="flex justify-center rounded-b-lg bg-inpay-black-haze-100 p-6">
              <div className="w-72">
                <form onSubmit={onSubmit} autoComplete="off">
                  <div className="mb-4 flex flex-col">
                    <label className="mb-0.5 pl-2 text-xs">Format</label>
                    <CsvSelector />
                  </div>
                  <div className="mb-4 flex flex-col">
                    <label className="mb-0.5 pl-2 text-xs">Transfer type</label>
                    <Selector
                      selectChoices={localInstrumentsOptions}
                      onChange={onLocalInstrumentChange}
                      name="localInstruments"
                      disabled={
                        !localInstrumentsOptions ||
                        localInstrumentsOptions.length === 0
                      }
                      defaultValue={
                        localInstrumentsOptions?.length === 1
                          ? localInstrumentsOptions[0].value
                          : undefined
                      }
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="mb-4 flex flex-col">
                    <label className="mb-0.5 pl-2 text-xs">Corridor</label>
                    <Selector
                      selectChoices={corridorsOptions}
                      onChange={onCorridorChange}
                      name="corridor"
                      disabled={
                        !corridorsOptions || corridorsOptions.length === 0
                      }
                      value={getValues('corridor')}
                      defaultValue={
                        corridorsOptions?.length === 1
                          ? corridorsOptions[0].label
                          : undefined
                      }
                    />
                    {console.log(
                      corridorsOptions?.length === 1
                        ? corridorsOptions[0].label
                        : undefined
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="mb-10 flex flex-col">
                    <label className="mb-0.5 pl-2 text-xs">Data required</label>
                    <Selector
                      selectChoices={productSchemasOptions}
                      onChange={onProductSchemaChange}
                      name="productSchema"
                      disabled={
                        !productSchemasOptions ||
                        productSchemasOptions.length === 0
                      }
                      value={getValues('productSchema')}
                      defaultValue={
                        productSchemasOptions?.length === 1
                          ? productSchemasOptions[0].label
                          : undefined
                      }
                    />
                  </div>
                  {dowloaded === false ? (
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="inpay-button w-full"
                      disabled={!formState.isValid}
                    >
                      Download CSV template
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      className="inpay-button w-full"
                      onClick={() => onClose(false)}
                    >
                      CSV dowloaded, close window
                    </button>
                  )}

                  {formState.errors.base && (
                    <div
                      role="alert"
                      className="mt-2 rounded-2xl bg-rose-200 p-3 text-sm text-inpay-red-600"
                      style={{
                        filter: 'drop-shadow(0 0 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.16))'
                      }}
                    >
                      {formState.errors.base.message}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </DialogContent>
        </DialogOverlay>
      </DialogPortal>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

This is the child component where I render the Selector, the issue is that even though the default value (string) and the matchingValue (object) are logged in the useEffect, matched and passed to the setCurrentItem state, the selector won't know when to use the defaultValue. So the preselection never works for some reasons. I am a bit confused if it is a limit of the library or if it is some mistake a made. Here below the selector:

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectItemText,
  SelectPortal,
  SelectScrollDownButton,
  SelectScrollUpButton,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
  SelectViewport
} from '@radix-ui/react-select';
import { ChevronUpIcon, ChevronDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline';

import cn from 'classnames';
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge';

interface SelectorClassNames {
  loadingClassName?: string;
  formButtonClassName?: string;
  selectedItemClassName?: string;
  selectContentClassName?: string;
  selectItemListClassName?: string;
}
export interface SelectChoice {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

interface Props {
  defaultValue?: string;
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
  classNames?: SelectorClassNames;
  selectChoices: SelectChoice[];
  name?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  value?: string;
}

const Selector: FC<Props> = ({
  defaultValue,
  onChange,
  classNames,
  selectChoices,
  name,
  disabled,
  value
}) => {
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState<SelectChoice | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  const [availableList, setAvailableList] = useState<SelectChoice[]>([]);
  const [opened, onOpenChange] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const selectTriggerProps = {
    className: twMerge(
      cn(
        'group flex items-center h-12 select-none rounded-lg bg-white px-4 text-left shadow-plain',
        classNames?.formButtonClassName,
        {
          'group hover:shadow-plain-lg cursor-pointer': !disabled,
          'stroke-inpay-black-haze-700 stroke-1.5 group hover:none text-inpay-black-haze-700':
            disabled,
          'bg-inpay-gray-100': disabled && currentItem?.value
        }
      )
    )
  };

  const selectedItemProps = {
    className: twMerge(
      cn(
        'group flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center px-4 rounded-t-lg outline-offset-[-1px] hover:bg-inpay-green-200 hover:text-inpay-green-700 border-none focus:outline-none',
        classNames?.selectedItemClassName,
        {
          'px-4': disabled
        }
      )
    )
  };

  const selectItemListProps = {
    className: twMerge(
      cn(
        'group h-12 flex items-center cursor-pointer px-4 outline-offset-[-1px] first:rounded-t-lg last:rounded-b-lg hover:bg-inpay-green-200 hover:text-inpay-green-700 border-none focus:outline-none',
        classNames?.selectItemListClassName
      )
    )
  };

  const selectContentProps = {
    className: twMerge(
      cn(
        `${
          currentItem
            ? ' relative z-50 select-none overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white shadow-plain-lg w-72'
            : 'relative z-50 select-none overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white shadow-plain-lg w-72'
        }`,
        classNames?.selectContentClassName
      )
    )
  };
  const onValueChange = (value: string) => {
    if (selectChoices) {
      const matchingValue = selectChoices.find(
        (element) => element.value == value
      );
      if (matchingValue) {
        setCurrentItem({ ...matchingValue });
        setAvailableList(
          selectChoices.filter((i) => i.value != matchingValue.value)
        );
        onChange && onChange(value);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultValue) {
      console.log(selectChoices, 'selectChoices'); // gets logged correctly
      const newValue = selectChoices.find((i) => i.label === defaultValue);
      console.log(defaultValue, 'defaultValue'); // gets logged correctly
      if (!newValue) {
        console.error('can not find new value');
      }
      setCurrentItem(newValue);
      console.log(newValue, 'new value'); // gets logged correctly

      setAvailableList(selectChoices.filter((i) => i.value != defaultValue));
    }
  }, [defaultValue, selectChoices]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAvailableList(selectChoices);
    setCurrentItem(undefined);
  }, [selectChoices]);

  return (
    <Select
      onValueChange={onValueChange}
      onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
      name={name}
      disabled={disabled}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      value={value}
    >
      <SelectTrigger {...selectTriggerProps}>
        <SelectValue
          placeholder={
            <div className="flex">
              <div className="flex-1"></div>
              <ChevronDownIcon
                className={cn('w-1/12 stroke-inpay-black-haze-700 stroke-1.5', {
                  'group-hover:stroke-inpay-black-500': !disabled
                })}
              />
            </div>
          }
        />
      </SelectTrigger>
      <SelectPortal>
        <SelectContent {...selectContentProps}>
          <SelectScrollUpButton className="flex justify-center">
            <ChevronUpIcon className="h-10 w-6 stroke-1.5" />
          </SelectScrollUpButton>
          <SelectViewport>
            {currentItem && (
              <SelectItem
                key={currentItem.value}
                value={currentItem.value}
                {...selectedItemProps}
              >
                <SelectItemText>
                  <div className="flex">
                    <div className="flex-1">
                      <div>{currentItem.label}</div>
                    </div>
                    {opened ? (
                      <ChevronUpIcon className="w-1/12 stroke-inpay-black-500 stroke-1.5" />
                    ) : (
                      <ChevronDownIcon className="w-1/12 stroke-inpay-black-haze-700 stroke-1.5 group-hover:stroke-inpay-black-500" />
                    )}
                  </div>
                </SelectItemText>
              </SelectItem>
            )}

            {availableList.map((item, index) => (
              <SelectItem
                key={item?.value}
                value={item.value}
                {...selectItemListProps}
              >
                <SelectItemText>
                  <div className="flex">
                    <div className="flex-1">{item.label}</div>
                    {index == 0 && !currentItem && (
                      <ChevronUpIcon className="w-1/12 stroke-inpay-black-500 stroke-1.5" />
                    )}
                  </div>
                </SelectItemText>
              </SelectItem>
            ))}
          </SelectViewport>
          <SelectScrollDownButton className="flex justify-center">
            <ChevronDownIcon className="h-10 w-6 stroke-1.5" />
          </SelectScrollDownButton>
        </SelectContent>
      </SelectPortal>
    </Select>
  );
};

export default Selector;
```

Any clues ?